# Can MS Outlook be made to maximize to the same folder as when it was minimized?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In MS Outlook 2016 (Office 365), if you have more than one email account, one of them has to be set as default. If you minimize Outlook to the system tray and later maximize it, it will then reopen to the default email account instead of whatever email account you were in when you first minimized Outlook. Is there any setting, registry hack, workaround, or VBA code that can force Outlook to maximize to the same email account or folder you were in when you first minimized it?
<sup>Google searches I've tried have turned up nothing usefull</sup>

Comment: What Outlook version do you use?

Comment: @thims, sorry. I should have included that in the original question. It has been edited.